# How to use typescript-redux-query in my React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I generated an api SDK using [OpenAPI typescript-redux-query](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-redux-query/). Unfortunately it does not create any `README` file, like many other generators do, and I have no idea how should I use it.

An example project can be found [on github](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-redux-query/builds/with-npm-version/src), but I'm not sure if that's up to date.

How should I initialize this SDK, and how to use it in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [redux-query](https://github.com/amplitude/redux-query) project that the OpenApi generator uses was last updated 2 years ago. It seems to be abandoned, and since the [redux-query generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-redux-query/) is not well documented, I don't suggest using them.

I ended up using the [Redux Toolkit generator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-generation). It can also generate an SDK from your OpenAPI definitions, and the [rtk-query documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query) explains well how to use them.